# How to create IPA based on other .p12 certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

After reviewing a lot of websites including apple dev portal. I ended up with no clue about how to proceed in the following case:
I am an IOS developer, I have my own account with Apple and my own certificates. I developed an Application for another client, and he has his own Apple Certificates and account in app store.
I have to create an IPA file, firstly for cient testing and later on for uploading to APP STORE but not with my own apple account but the client's account, he does not want to give me his credential but he sent me two files: .cer and .p12 certificates for development. I tried to use them to generate the .IPA file but it seems I only can use my own certificates as I am logged in in XCODE with my Apple ID. I dont want to share my code with them in order they generate the .IPA file. So what options do I have for creating the .IPA file?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as using your client's signing identity to sign the app, they would have to invite you to their Development Team, which is done through AppStoreConnect. It looks like you would have the access you need at the "Developer" role level (https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/). After you've accepted the invite, you would need to change your Team in XCode to be your client's team.

For testing purposes, your options would be:

- Ad-Hoc distribution of the IPA file, along with hosting the Over-The-Air installation process (and IPA file) somewhere. Google's Firebase now has a process which seems like it might make Ad-Hoc distribution a little easier as well, but I've only done quick testing with it (https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution#example_implementation_path).
- Uploading (signed with your client's cert) via AppStoreConnect, which would provide the builds to the testers in TestFlight, but would also be what you would have to do for eventual distribution in the App Store anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The testing part of the answer @BenW provides is correct.
for signing, you don't have to be added to the development team, you could use fastlane or xcodebuild command to generate a signed build using .p12 and .certificate files.